# C++ possible memory leak reading file

Tags: c++, memory-management, file-io

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm trying to read a proprietary file format. I know the header format, and I've created a struct `RTIHeader` with the necessary fields.

My test code reads bytes from the file and copies them into the same memory space as the header struct, effectively reconstituting it. My problem is that every time I run the test code (just calling the constructor) I get a different value! My theory is that I do not fully understand `memcpy`.

```
struct RTIHeader decode(char* memblock){
    struct RTIHeader header;
    memcpy(&header,&memblock,sizeof(RTIHeader));
    return header;
}

RTIFile::RTIFile(const char* filename){
    // open the file in binary input mode with the pointer at the end
    std::ifstream file(filename,
                       std::ios::in |
                       std::ios::binary |
                       std::ios::ate);

    std::ifstream::pos_type size;
    char * memblock;
    RTIHeader header;

    // if the file didn't open, throw an error
    if(!file.is_open()){
        //TODO learn about C++ error handling
        return;
    }
    // use pointer position to determine file size
    size = file.tellg();
    // read file
    memblock = new char [sizeof(RTIHeader)];
    file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock,sizeof(RTIHeader));

    header = decode(memblock);

    std::cout << (unsigned int)header.signature[0] << "\n";

    // still need to read the rest of the file
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: We need the definition of RTIHeader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *address* of `memblock` as the second argument of `memcpy`. Since `memblock` is a parameter to the function, you will just be copying chunks of memory off your stack.

To fix, just pass the pointer directly:

```
memcpy(&header,memblock,sizeof(RTIHeader));
```

By the way, since you are returning the structure by value, you will incur an *extra* memcpy as the returned value is copied in full (unless your compiler optimizes it). To avoid this, you should consider passing the target structure as a pointer to `decode`, as in

```
struct RTIHeader *decode(struct RTIHeader *header, char* memblock){
    memcpy(header, memblock, sizeof(RTIHeader));
    return header;
}
```

Then you just have to do

```
decode(&header, memblock);
```

which is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, that was fast! SO tells me I need to wait 7 minutes before accepting your answer but that was the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on optimization as well, very insightful!

Comment: You should also be careful with packing. File formats usually assume packing of 1 (no gaps between fields), but the struct in the code is declared with the default packing (depending on the tools you use) and might not be of the same size/layout as file format declares.

Comment: Okay, so would I just add `#pragma pack(1)` before `RTIHeader`?

Comment: It's compiler dependent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274055/portable-way-of-writing-a-c-struct-to-a-file-serialisation-for-c.

Comment: @Ryan Do not this pointer stuff that's being recommended in this answer.  This is exactly the kind of stuff you should NOT do unless the profiler tells you.  Not only will ALL modern compilers optimize away the copies, the more recent ones will use move semantics when appropriate.  By passing the return in by address you limit your ability to initialize to useful values.  Furthermore, if you do in fact find that you're making unnecessary and slow copies you should be passing by reference, NOT by pointer.  This person is giving you really bad advice.

Comment: This is a *POD struct*, not a class object. None of the bits about move semantics or initialization values matters.